# PostgreSQL + Hibernate + Spring auto create database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql

I'm working with PostgreSQL and Spring 4 and want my app auto create database when it running.

My Entity Class is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user", schema = "public")
public class User extends BaseEntity {

    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Integer contractId;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(Integer id) {
        super(id);
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "usr_id", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "usr_name", nullable = true, length = -1)
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "usr_contract_id", nullable = true)
    public Integer getContractId() {
        return contractId;
    }

    public void setContractId(Integer contractId) {
        this.contractId = contractId;
    }

}
```

HibernateConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement(proxyTargetClass = true)
@PropertySources({
    @PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.properties")})
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
public class HibernateConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private MultiTenantConnectionProvider multiTenantConnectionProvider;

    @Autowired
    private CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver currentTenantIdentifierResolver;

    public HibernateConfig() {}

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() throws Exception {

        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());

        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] {
            "com.xxx.xxx.model",
        });

        return sessionFactory;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(DIALECT, environment.getRequiredProperty(DIALECT));
        properties.put(SHOW_SQL, environment.getRequiredProperty(SHOW_SQL));
        properties.put(FORMAT_SQL, environment.getRequiredProperty(FORMAT_SQL));
        properties.put(HBM2DDL_AUTO, environment.getRequiredProperty(HBM2DDL_AUTO));

        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
        return txManager;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate(SessionFactory s) {
        HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate = new HibernateTemplate(s);
        return hibernateTemplate;
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
# Database connection settings:
jdbc.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/database
jdbc.username=postgres
jdbc.password=111111

hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql=false
hibernate.format_sql=false
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update

spring.datasource.initialSize=50
spring.datasource.maxActive=200
spring.datasource.maxIdle=200
spring.datasource.minIdle=50
```

But when I running SQL to access table User, this will appear error: Table 'User' does not exist.

How can I make Hibernate to auto create database?

Comment: Have you tired hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create?

Comment: hey did you solve this? and how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The property `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` will do the trick for you. It automatically validates or exports schema DDL to the database when the SessionFactory is created. With create-drop, the database schema will be dropped when the SessionFactory is closed explicitly.

Hibernate can accept these options for the above property.

`validate`: validate the schema, makes no changes to the database.

`update`: update the schema.

`create`: creates the schema, destroying previous data.

`create-drop`: drop the schema at the end of the session.

Answer (score 29):

Postgres unlike mysql does not support `Create Database If not exist`.

Thus changing `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create` and changing URL `jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/database?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true`
won't work for you.

However you can try simulating the behavior as in below questions:

[Create Postgres database on the fly, if it doesn't exists using Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30280683/create-postgres-database-on-the-fly-if-it-doesnt-exists-using-hibernate)

[Simulate CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS for PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18389124/simulate-create-database-if-not-exists-for-postgresql)

Answer (score 9):

Try this way

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect

spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=123

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.session.store-type=none
```

This is work for me.

From the [*Automatic schema generation* section of the Hibernate User Guide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#configurations-hbmddl):

> `javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action`
>
> Setting to perform SchemaManagementTool actions automatically as part of the SessionFactory lifecycle. Valid options are defined by the **externalJpaName** value of the Action enum:
>
> - `none` - No action will be performed.
> - `create` - Database creation will be generated.
> - `drop` - Database dropping will be generated.
> - `drop-and-create` - Database dropping will be generated followed by database creation.

there `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update` ==> `update`, you can change according to your scenario.

Answer (score 5):

**Spring Boot**

Postgres does not support `createDatabaseIfNotExist=true`
So you can try similar way and it worked for me see [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYeuw.png)

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringSecurityJwtApplication{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SpringSecurityJwtApplication.class);
        Connection connection = null;
        Statement statement = null;
        try {
            logger.debug("Creating database if not exist...");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/", "postgres", "postgres");
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            statement.executeQuery("SELECT count(*) FROM pg_database WHERE datname = 'database_name'");
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.getResultSet();
            resultSet.next();
            int count = resultSet.getInt(1);

            if (count <= 0) {
                statement.executeUpdate("CREATE DATABASE database_name");
                logger.debug("Database created.");
            } else {
                logger.debug("Database already exist.");
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            logger.error(e.toString());
        } finally {
            try {
                if (statement != null) {
                    statement.close();
                    logger.debug("Closed Statement.");
                }
                if (connection != null) {
                    logger.debug("Closed Connection.");
                    connection.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                logger.error(e.toString());
            }
        }
        SpringApplication.run(SpringSecurityJwtApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is about hibernate dialect. You are using old one. You should use newer one like this.

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change

from:

```
@Table(name = "user") || @Entity(name="user")
```

to:

```
@Table(name = "users") || @Entity(name="users")
```

Because PostgreSQL has default "user"

Answer (score -3):

you can have a schema.sql script with `"CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS x;"` with

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
```

It should work