# Can Spring Data JPA automatically create database in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring Boot, Spring Data JPA and PostgreSQL.

A want to persist **User** entity to database **db_example**.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "my_user") // user is a reserved keyword in PostgreSQL
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;  
    private String name;    
    private String email;

    // getters and setters       
}
```

My **application.properties** is quite standart:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

spring.jpa.hibernate.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db_example
spring.datasource.username=springuser
spring.datasource.password=ThePassword
```

Is it possible to make database created while Spring Boot Application started?

In my case I got 
`org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: database "db_example" does not exist`

Comment: You need to manually create the `db_example` database on your PostgreSQL server and then this should work

Comment: Even if it could: do not do that. Creating a database requires an account with superuser privileges. And your application should **not** use such a database user to begin with that is a huge security risk. After all that is a one-time operation when you setup your server. And what's wrong with using the default database `postgres`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, actually I used to such behavior of MongoDB, it can create database automatically. I'm planning to create a few Spring Boot Microservices, which will store some data in PostgreSQL in a separate databases. So I wanted to automate this process.

Comment: Well, this is not how Postgres (or most relational databases for that matter) works. Creating a database is a task done during the installation and configuration of the database server, not something you do "ad hoc" when starting an application.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name What is wrong with this approach for development purposes?

Comment: @Andrew set those 2 properties in your `application.properties` file: `spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true`
`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create` (or create-drop or update)

Comment: @Pijotrek: because the database user you use during development should not have more privileges than the one used in production.

Comment: It sounds a bit paranoid to me, but that's only my opinion and I'm not an expert, rather a beginner. Obviously for production purposes I completely agree, but speeding up the development process is a good thing. I can't imagine asking DBA to do some changes in schema every time I change the field in my entity POJO...

Comment: @Pijotrek: I already have set this properties in my `application.properties`, as I pointed out in my question. Unfortunately it does't help - got `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: database "db_example" does not exist`

Comment: @Pijotrek: for a controlled deployment of schema changes, tools like Liquibase or Flyway are a much better solution

Answer (score 1):

So i configured this manually through application instead of using `application.yml` default properties [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54336507/create-schema-if-does-not-exist-by-using-spring-jpa-with-hibernate), In addition to those you just need to add the below one.

For more info [docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#configurations-hbmddl)

```
jpaProps.put("javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action", "update");
```